# Scroll To jQuery

Tags: jquery, scrollto

I have a fixed div with overflow auto on it and at the bottom of this container is an anchor, which I am trying to scroll to when a link is clicked. When the link is clicked more content is added to the container. I have a many links that can add more markup to the container each one varies in size but for testing I've just used the one

```
$("#scrollTo").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#inner').append(content);

    var offset = $("#formBottom").offset().top;

    $('#offset span').text(offset);

    $('#container').animate({
        scrollTop: offset
    }, 300);

});
```

The issue is with the top offset of the target element (You can see it in this fiddle) http://jsfiddle.net/doseone1986/333Mr/ the offset is correctly calculated on page load and works well when not appending to the container. There is a lot more going on in the real application, but this was enough to duplicate the issue.

What is the best way to get the correct position of the anchor after appending more content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of tracking the offset of the `#formBottom` anchor, why not just track the height of the `#inner` container?

http://jsfiddle.net/333Mr/1/

```
$('#offset span').text($("#inner").height());

$("#scrollTo").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#inner').append(content);

    var offset = $("#inner").height();

    $('#offset span').text(offset);

    $('#container').animate({
        scrollTop: offset
    }, 300);

});
```

Not to mention, there is an issue with your current code:

```
$('#inner').append(content);
```

This is adding more paragraphs BELOW the `#formBottom` anchor. So the anchor is no longer at the bottom as soon as you click `#scrollTo` once.

Comment: Yeah I added the anchor to the wrong place, It was meant to live underneath the "inner" div. But would have still functioned incorrectly. I'm liking the .height() usage keeps things nice and simple, sometimes it's so easy to forget the obvious. 

Thanks for your help